# Automate Exploding Text Jquery Jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, text

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/dNXVx/

How can I make this animate automatically?

I'm new to all this so any help is much appreciated!

```
    function fx(o)
{
  var $o=$(o);
      $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
      $o.css('position','relative');
      $('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
                               opacity:0,
                               fontSize:84,
                               top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
                               left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}

                       }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:12,top:0,left:0},1000);

}​
```

Comment: What do you want to happen automatically? Without click? Like this > http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/479/

Comment: Take a look at the ready method for jQuery.

Comment: @Vega precisely that, but not repeating. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the animate function to be called without click.. if that is the case you can call the function directly or use a timer for an effect. See below,

Change the span like below,

```
<span id="animateMe">click here</span>
```

And this script below the `fx` inside document ready,

**Direct Call:**

```
$(function() {
   fx('#animateMe');
});
```

**Timer (after 2 secs)**

```
$(function() {
   setTimeout(function () {
     fx('#animateMe');
   }, 2000); //2000 milli seconds = 2 secs
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/483/